# Do you really need a return when using 'when' method of Laravel query builder?

Tags: laravel, laravel-query-builder

Laravel documentation for its query builder has this example for the 'when' method:

```php
$users = DB::table('users')
                ->when($role, function ($query, $role) {
                    return $query->where('role_id', $role);
                })
                ->get();
```

Is the return keyword required? I ask because from what I can determine I do not see why it is needed.

Comment: you don't need the `return` here since `when` returns the builder by default anyway

Comment: @lagbox I guess you are correct

Comment: for your reference https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Database/Concerns/BuildsQueries.php#L205

Comment: you don't need return in when like ```$users = DB::table('users')->when($role, function ($query) use($role) {$query->where('role_id', $role);})->get();``` and ```$users``` will handle response as collection type, if you want response as array, you can add ```->all()``` after ```->get()``` or add ```$users->all()```